# Google maps style uipopovercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ipad, google-maps, uipopovercontroller

I have a universal app. On the iPad, when pressing an annotation pin it shows the callout bubble. When I press the desclosure button, it loads a uipopovercontroller with a detailed view. 
What I want to know is how I can load the uipopovercontroller the same way the Google Maps load the uipopovercontroller. Is there a guide out there to get just at neat?

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Comment: Could you please elaborate "the same way as Google Maps"? Do you refer to the positioning of the view?

Comment: I mean the same way as google maps on the iPad loads the UIPopoverContoller when pressing the disclosure button. By that I mean the animation from a callout bubble to a UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That popover in google maps appears to be a custom view, not an UIPopoverController supplied popover. Notice that the color of the callout popover is different from the color of the recent searches popover.

To get the same effect as google maps' callout, you'll need to make a custom view that looks like a popover, and add it as a subview of your map view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any suggestions on how to create the animation from the callout bubble to the UIPopovercontroller look-a-like? /P